# How to create a new column based on conditions in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe that has a column for age and a column with a list of health conditions. I want to create a new column that indicates if a person is `high risk' based on their age and health conditions. So, anyone who is over 40 or has at least one condition from a certain list (i.e. obesity, diabetes, hypertension) has 'Yes' in the new 'High risk' column.

I used the code below to filter for age

```
df['High risk'] = np.where(df['Age'] >= 40, 'Yes', 'No')
```

But, I don't know how to search the health conditions column to filter for the other conditions. Ultimately, I would like my dataframe to look like this:

```
   Age     Health Conditions    High risk
0   45    anemia, hypertension     Yes
1   26    diabetes, obesity        Yes
2   38         anemia               No
3   56     arthritis, asthma       Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` takes three arguments. The first one is a logic array. You can try `str.contains` on `Health Condition` in addition a logic statement on `Age` column. What I have come up with is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Age":[45,26,38,56], "Health Conditions":["anemia, hypertension", "diabetes, obesity", "anemia", "arthritis, asthma"]})
mask = (df["Age"] > 40) | (df["Health Conditions"].str.contains("obesity|diabetes|hypertension"))
df["High risk"] = np.where(mask, "Yes", "No")
df
```

##### Output

|  | Age | Health Conditions | High risk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 45 | anemia, hypertension | Yes |
| 1 | 26 | diabetes, obesity | Yes |
| 2 | 38 | anemia | No |
| 3 | 56 | arthritis, asthma | Yes |

##### Explanation

`str.contains` take an argument which is a regex pattern. `obesity|diabetes|hypertension` indicates whether the input string is one of these three mentioned diseases or not. If you are interested in adding more diseases to this condition, simply follow the pattern used in this regex.("|" indicates OR).

Answer (score 0):

How about this, assuming high risk is over 40 or has anemia:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[45, 'anemia'], [30, 'anemia'], [30, 'arthritis']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Age', 'Conditions'])

def HighRisk(row):
  if row['Age'] >= 40:
    HR = True
  if 'anemia' in row['Conditions']:
    HR = True
  else:
    HR = False
  return HR #Returns HR = True if high risk, False if not

df['High risk'] = df.apply(HighRisk, axis = 1)

print(df)
```

gives output:

```
Age Conditions  High risk
0   45  anemia  True
1   30  anemia  True
2   30  arthritis   False
```

You can adjust the `HighRisk` function as per your definition of what makes a person high risk.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use boolean operations for things like this.

```
hr_conditions = ["obesity", "diabetes", "hypertension"]
case1 = df["Age"] > 40
case2 = df["Conditions"].apply(lambda x: any([c in x for c in hr_conditions))
df["HighRisk"] = case1 & case2
```